# Is Apple’s Face ID less secure in the dark?

Tags: biometrics, apple

Apple’s FaceID on iPhone X works even in the dark using infrared light to “illuminate” your face with an IR projection and collect the features.

When designing the algorithms that confirm a user’s face, does Apple lower the “validation thresholds” when running in the dark to ensure a better user experience?

Can an attacker trying to fool FaceID with a replicated scanning target be more successful in poor lighting conditions?

Comment: I don’t think it states explicitly that depth sense accuracy is not influenced by ambiental lighting. That’s the essence of the problem because heuristic algorithms are used to estimate the depth. I find it hard to believe that the algorithms perform the same no matter the lighting conditions. But perhaps this is not the right forum to ask this question.

Comment: That’s a weak assumption. Apple’s doc doesn’t state anyhting about how security of FaceID varies on external conditions. It’s just a marketing doc. https://www.extremetech.com/mobile/255771-apple-iphone-x-truedepth-camera-works this describes that flood illuminator is a technology to enhance usabilty in poor lighting so it looks like IR is not enough.

Comment: So fundamentally, a 3D printed mask would be able to fool a depth-based only system and that’s the reasoning for which iphone needs more than TrueDepth camera. And Flood Illuminator is a solution. Question is if it works similarly no matter the lighting.

Comment: So, now that you have some basic info, and you've provided foundational details, let's focus this question.

Comment: If you looked up "Flood Illuminator" you will see that it, too, is IR.